# "Skipping" a selected column on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, selection

I have some data in column A:

[Column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbsRC.png)

I want to select the ONLY data in column B (without column A):

[Column B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGJqs.png)

Of course, I could simply drag with my cursor to do so. However, the data I am working with has many rows and so I need to scroll down; is there some keyboard shortcut I can use?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is SHIFT + CTRL + END keys pressed together. Click on a single cell in the first row, then press SHIFT + CTRL + END to select the entire column up to the last entry in that column.

Comment: That selects both columns though? On a mac, I'm using fn+right arrow instead of END.

Comment: Since you are on Mac I suggest adding a Tag to the list or mentioning it in your question, so that you shall be guided appropriately.

Comment: What @patkim means, is that you need to be on column B, then press the keys.

Comment: Looks like I articulated my question badly- I wanted to base my selection on the rows selected in the previous column, not where the end of column values are.

Comment: So as an example, in Col A if you have selected A1:A503 then you wish to select B1:B503 in Col B? However then I suppose Excel should unselect A1:A503 and only select B1:B503? And what if there's a split selection e.g. you have Selected A1:A10 and then A30:A40, together? I suggest please edit your question to include this info.

Comment: @patkim I have edited the images to better reflect the problem. Yes, that is what I want! I haven't needed to use this for a split selection yet but I suppose that in a split selection both selections would be shifted one column.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "select" : do you want to move the selection area from column A to B? What for?

Comment: Yeah, I want to move the selection area to column B, but with the rows corresponding to the ones previous selected in column A. I want to do this to paste truncated x and y values into a certain set of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Shift + right arrow selects the corresponding rows of both A and B

Then Shift + Tab moves the active cell to the last cell in the range (is it Option + tab on a Mac? Whatever reverses direction on various shortcut keys)

Then shift + right arrow deselects column A

Optionally, tab moves the active cell to the top of the selected range (you might not need this, depending on why you are doing all this anyway).

I see you have a Mac, but I don't so I cannot test, but these are standard

Answer (score 0):

Read your comments concerning what you truly want to do. Much clearer.

Yes, there is a very simple way.

Your column A cells are selected at this moment — that's the starting point. Not a fresh, some cell somewhere is selected and you want to go to column B and select cells.

So:

1. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>. This includes the cells in column B corresponding to the selected cells in column A.
2. Still holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press <kbd>TAB</kbd>. This moves the selected cell to a cell in column B.
3. Still holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.

Your selected cells now do NOT include column A at all, but do include all the column B cells that corresponded to the starting selection of column A cells.

*(Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> down is critical to maintaining the selected characteristic here. Do any of this without remembering to keep it held down and suddenly you'll have no cells selected.)*

(You can vary this as needed. Maybe you'd like to press <kbd>Shift-TAB</kbd> to go to the end of the selected list. No problem. Etc.)

Comment: Thank you for reposting my solution but with pretty images for the key presses. If you thought it was right, you could always just upvote it.